# Contact Form 7 MailChimp Extension not working properly

Tags: wordpress, mailchimp, contact-form-7

I'm having trouble getting the Contact Form 7 MailChimp Extension to work properly on my website (https://www.jewelrybysarahjordan.com/contact).  I contacted the plugin author twice (once on 10/02/2018 and again on 10/15/2018) using his preferred contact method. Now, 20 days after my original message, I still have not received any response.  I hope that someone here can please help!

Click to see my [MailChimp merge fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6NMW.jpg).

Click to see my [plugin settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdLTK.jpg).

Here is the situation:

I would like to leave the "Subscriber Email" and "Subscriber Name" fields blank because I want to use ONLY custom fields.  You can see my configuration in the attached screen shot.  However, with this configuration, the plugin literally does nothing.  I tested with the debug logger enabled and not a single message was written to the log.  Contact Form 7 works properly, but the MailChimp integration is dead.

When I put "[email-address]" into the "Subscriber Email" field (still leaving "Subscriber Name" blank), the MailChimp integration works but only partially.  The subscriber's email address and last name are correctly added to my mailing list, but the first name is blank.  The debug log now contains some information.

When I put "[email-address]" into the "Subscriber Email" field and "[last-name]" into the "Subscriber Name" field, the MailChimp integration works, but again, it only works partially.  The subscriber's email address and last name are correctly added to my mailing list, but the first name is incorrectly set to [last-name].

Can you please help me sort this out?  I may not be a web developer, but I am a software engineer so I have no problem editing the plugin code myself until the author decides to fix it for real.  I could just use some guidance on what to do.